# C++ - Create a 2D copy constructor

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to study for my final and I tried putting together my dynamic 2d array copy constructor. When I created my backup and printed it to see if it worked, it prints out the same memory address I believe over and over again. This is my copy constructor:
Update, here is where I read in data from my file .txt

```
void Matrix::readTemps(ifstream &inFile) 
{
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < mnumRows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < mnumCols; col++)
            {
                inFile >> Temps[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
}
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix & original) 
{
    mnumRows = original.mnumRows;
    mnumCols = original.mnumCols;
    Temps = new double*[mnumRows];
    for (int row = 0; row < mnumRows; row++) 
        Temps[row] = new double[mnumCols];
}
```

---

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix & second)  
{  
    if (this != &second)
    {
        delete[] Temps;
        mnumRows = second.mnumRows;
        mnumCols = second.mnumCols;
        Temps = new double*[second.mnumRows];
        for (int row = 0; row < mnumRows; row++)
            Temps[row] = new double[mnumCols];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

UPDATE, and this is in my main.cpp:

```
//Example of overloaded assignment operator.
Matrix TestMatrix;
TestMatrix = NYCTemps;

//Example of copy constructor.
Matrix copyOfMatrix(NYCTemps); // The traditional way to copy the phonebook.

NYCTemps.display();
copyOfMatrix.display();
cout << endl;
```

I believe my assignment overloaded operator is correct as well, but I am posting it just to confirm it is good from more clever minds.

Comment: Where is copying of array values itself?

Comment: Read about the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). Show an [MCVE] in your question

Comment: Ok I updated the issue with more code, but the main thing I need to know is if my copy constructor and overloaded assignment operator are correct. The file im pulling data from is a random text file of temperatures that ranges from 1869 to 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your version of copy constructor 
and copy assignment operator you only allocate
memory for 2d array but you don't copy values from original 
matrix to new one.

You should add these lines in both methods

```
for (int r = 0; r < mnumRows; ++r)
    for (int c = 0; c < mnumCols; ++c)
        Temps[r][c] = original.Temps[r][c];  // or second.Temps[r][c]
```

Temps is 2d array so in copy assignment operator 
it must be deleted by (firstly delete memory allocated for columns in every row then delete memory of rows)

```
for (int r = 0; r < mnumRows; ++r)
    delete[] Temps[r];
delete[] Temps;
```

Comment: I added the lines, but they are giving me the error: Exception thrown at 0x001E4576 in ClimateChange.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.              I get that error at this line: Temps[r][c] = original.Temps[r][c];

Comment: @SmithJohn Error means that you are writing into not-allocated memory, so you added these lines before creating array. Add these lines after `Temps = new double*[mnumRows];
    for (int row = 0; row < mnumRows; row++) 
        Temps[row] = new double[mnumCols];` not before.

Comment: Thank you, that's what the issue was. Really appreciate it.